# JQuery UI Tab with form in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I try to make user registation form. I have two user types and want to make two JQuery UI tabs  with forms. But tab is empty and in java script console error "GET http://localhost/ParcDocs/Admin/Users/AddWorker 500 (Internal Server Error)".

Code of user registration page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#tabContainer").tabs();
    });
  </script>

  <div id="tabContainer">
    <ul>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Пользователь", "AddUser", "Users", null, null)</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Сотрудник", "AddWorker", "Users", null, null)</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

PartialView code:

```
@model ParcDocs.Models.WorkerUser

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddWorker", "Users"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Пользователь</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleId, ((IEnumerable<ParcDocs.Models.Role>)ViewBag.PossibleRoles).Select(option => new SelectListItem
       {
           Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Name),
           Value = option.Id.ToString(),
           Selected = (Model != null) && (option.Id == Model.RoleId)
       }), "Выберете роль пользователя")
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Добавить" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult AddWorker()
        {
            var model = new WorkerUser();
            return PartialView(model);
        }
```

Same behavior this second tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be returning a PartialViewResult, rather than an ActionResult. Put a breakpoint on public ActionResult AddWorker() and see what exception you get. Paste it here so that we have more information.